# maildev : issue at startup after installation completed

Tags: node.js

I have installed maildev, but when I run maildev I am getting this error
[image]

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: have you tried to update your node version?

Comment: I installed the 1.0.0 version of maildev and it worked.

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: yes it does work